# Transponse data from multiple rows into 1 Column

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to make 1 column out of multiple columns. I am struggling to do it in MSSQL.

```
ID     | Type1  | Type2
0      | Yellow | Blue
1      | Blue   | Yellow
```

And I want to have:

```
ID     | TYPE_ALL | TYPE
0      | Yellow   | Type1
0      | Blue     | Type2
1      | Blue     | Type1
1      | Yellow   | Type2
```

Please, do you know how to do it?

Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

An UNPIVOT can be used here:

```
SELECT *
FROM Table
UNPIVOT
(Type_ALL FOR TYPE IN 
  (Type1, Type2)
)AS unpvt;
```

Comment: Great! Thank you. I need to learn more about pivot and unpivot, they seem very useful. THX a lot! I am not a big fan of union with multiple columns :D

Comment: This might work. Can you query using the terms above?

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT ID, Type1 AS TYPE_ALL, 'Type1' AS [TYPE] FROM YourTable 
UNION ALL
SELECT ID, Type2 AS TYPE_ALL, 'Type2' AS [TYPE] FROM YourTable
```

Answer (score 3):

If you don't want to do an `UNPIVOT`, you can instead use a `UNION` query:

```
SELECT ID,
       Type1 AS TYPE_ALL,
       'Type1' AS TYPE
FROM yourTable
UNION ALL
SELECT ID,
       Type2,
       'Type2'
FROM yourTable
ORDER BY ID
```